# Install module 'requests' on python 3.5.1 mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python and have recently installed python 3.5.1 and am trying to install the module 'requests' by writing the following in terminal:

`pip install requests`

However I am receiving the following error. Thank you so much in advance for any help that you can give!

```
Collecting requests  
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Installing collected packages: requests  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main  
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run  
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install  
    **kwargs  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install  
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-  py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files  
    isolated=self.isolated,  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files  
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 315, in clobber  
    ensure_dir(destdir)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-  py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir  
    os.makedirs(path)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs  
    mkdir(name, mode)  
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to install `requests` to a place you do not have permissions to do so.

If you `sudo` it, ie. `sudo pip install requests` it will succeed. Else you can look into virtual environments to manage dependancies locally.

Also, you're installing the Python 2.7.x version of `requests`, due to using the `Python 2.7.x` version of `pip`. You'll need to use the `pip` for 3.5 explicitly if that's the one you want to install. There will either be a `pip3.5` binary, or you can launch it with the full path to pip for Python 3.5.x